# Transfer cookies across domains in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

I've got a proxy set up in nodejs that goes to one of our backend servers for data; some of that data (such as session id) is stored as cookies.  what I want to do is have the proxy get the remote cookies, push then into the header of the response to the original request, then send the response back.  I'm close, but hit a snag:

```
app.get(/\/json\/(.+)/, getJson);

var getJson = function(req, response1) {
    response1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    var before1stWrite = true;
    utils.setCookies(response1, ["floo=flum"])   // this works

    var options = {
        host : config.scraperUrl.replace('http://', ''),
        path : '/rwd/' + req.params[0] + '?' + querystring.stringify(req.query),
        method : "GET",
        rejectUnauthorized : false
    };

    var request = https.request(options, function(response2) {
        response2.setEncoding('utf8');
        // utils.setCookies(response1, ["flib=flah"])      // this fails, too

        response2.on('data', function(d) {
            if (before1stWrite) {
              console.log(response2.headers['set-cookie']);   // remote's cookies
              utils.setCookies(response1, ["flib=flah"])      // this fails
              before1stWrite = false;
            }
            response1.write(d);
        });

        response2.on('end', function() {
            response1.end()
        });
    });

    request.end();

    request.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error("error occurred: " + e.message);
        response1.end();
    });
}
```

setCookies(response1, cookies) just loops thru the cookies and does 
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie)

The problem is that it looks like the headers have been baked by the time the second setCookies is called; moving the method to the 'data' event handler does not help. The error I get is:

```
http.js:689
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
```

Any way to add headers to response1 that I receive from the response2?

---

**UPDATE**

I fixed the code to be sure that the attempt to write to headers of response1 was done before any other writes; it is not a fix, however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot send headers after data has started flowing. Did you try setting the header after this line?

```
response.setEncoding('utf8');
```

Also, did you consider using streams rather than transferring in chunks? http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: I'm not setting the header in the response received, I'm attempting to set it in the res passed in. I suspect that app.get(), once it returns, has written the headers on the first response object (res).

Anyhow, I am able to call response.headers['set-cookie'] in the line below setEncoding, but still can't write to the original, passed-in res header.  Same error.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to buffer the data.
Doing this is pretty much like piping:

```
        response.on('data', function(d) {
          res.write(d);
        });
```

so you're sending the response straight away. Haven't tried it but this should work:

```
var data = "";
response.on('data', function(d) {
  data += d;
});

response.on('end', function() {
    console.log(response.headersSent);
    console.log(response.headers['set-cookie']);
    utils.setCookies(res, ["flib=flah"])
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
});
```

Just remember you're buffering all that data into memory, not recommended for large responses.

Comment: No, that does not work, either. I'm clarifying my example:  response1 is the response I pass in to the getJSON method; response2 is the response I get back from the call within the getJSON method; I am not reading from response1, but I am trying to update the headers on response1 based on what I get back from response2. 

Read up on this some more and it could be a middleware issue where headers are written to but not following the correct protocol.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about it. But I think the problem in that app.get() bakes the headers before the callback function is called. Guessing, but that's what seems to be happening.  If I could make a dirty synchronous call I could determine that for sure.